# npx create-react-app command is throwing this error. what should i do to resolve this

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, reactjs, shell

I've been trying to use the 'npx create-react-app' command to create a new React application, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. Has anyone else experienced this issue recently?

I have a stable internet connection and have made sure that Node.js is up to date on my system. However, whenever I run the 'npx create-react-app' command, it fails to initiate the React application creation process. I've received an error message, but it doesn't provide much information about the problem.

I've tried multiple times and even searched for similar issues online, but I couldn't find any recent reports or solutions related to this specific problem. My global npm packages, including 'create-react-app,' are also up to date.

I'm not sure if this is a problem with my local setup or if there might be an issue with the 'npx create-react-app' command itself. If anyone has encountered a similar problem or has any insights on how to resolve this, I would greatly appreciate your help.

```bash
npm ERR! code ENOSPC
npm ERR! syscall write
npm ERR! errno -4055
npm ERR! nospc ENOSPC: no space left on device, write
npm ERR! nospc There appears to be insufficient space on your system to finish.
npm ERR! nospc Clear up some disk space and try again.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-27T08_57_38_099Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: You say the error message doesn't provide much information, but "no space left on device" seems like a pretty clear error message to me. Have you checked how much disk space is available?

Comment: Please remove the java tag?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the latest version of Node.js installed. You can check your Node.js version by running the following command in your terminal:

- node -v

Make sure that you have the latest version of create-react-app installed. You can check your create-react-app version by running the following command in your terminal:

- npm ls create-react-app

Try running the npx create-react-app command with the --verbose flag. This will provide more information about the error that you're getting.

- npx create-react-app --verbose my-app

If you're still having trouble, you can try creating a new React application using the create-react-app website. This will create a new application in a temporary directory, so you won't have to worry about making any changes to your local environment.
https://create-react-app.dev/: https://create-react-app.dev/

If you've tried all of the above and you're still having trouble, you can post a question on the Create React App: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/discussions discussion forum.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Creating a react app does require some storage, the error indicates that you don't have enough, make sure you have at least 1 GB available on your system.

Answer (score 0):

[@Priyansh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22293431/priyansh): It seems like that you are trying to install on a drive that either has no space, or has no permission to write.

You may try:

- Free some disk space
  OR
- Set the tmp folder somewhere with more space: `npm config set tmp /path/to/big/drive/tmp`
  OR
- Build Node yourself and install it somewhere writable with lots of space.

Reference : https://docs.npmjs.com/common-errors#no-space